# How can I convert this useEffect firebase onAuthStateChanged function to class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is the code I used in the function component

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setIsLoggedIn(!!user);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });
```

Here is my try on the class component.

```
componentDidUpdate(
    prevProps: LessonDrawerProps,
    prevState: LessonDrawerState
  ) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            this.setState({
              isLoggedIn: true,
            });
          }
        });
}
```

The class onAuthStateChanged detection is not working properly as in the function component.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The `componentDidUpdate` fires when the component was updated, which in your case seems to never happen (or at least not in time). You actually want to start listening for auth state changes as soon as the component is added to the widget tree.

You'll want to put the `onAutStateChanged` in the `componentDidMount` instead of in `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I am currently using the statement inside the navbar. In which if i use `onAutStateChanged` in the `componentdidmount` the navbar always don't update the state. I mean when user logged in the text is still `login` not changed into `logout`

Comment: That's unexpected, but I can't say why it's going wrong based without a reproduction. Can you edit your question to show the updated code? We need to see the minimal code with which to reproduce the problem. It typically helps if you reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin or stackblitz, and then include that code (and a link to it) in the question.